# How do I use Linux, Mac's "touch" command in Windows?

Tags: next.js, github-pages

How do I use Linux, Mac's "touch" command in Windows?

my code :

`"deploy": "next build && next export && touch out/.nojekyll && git add -f out/ && git commit -m 'deploy to gh-pages' && git subtree push --prefix out origin gh-pages"`

i want touch to window command.

I'm trying to prevent the consequences of not being copied to the final site because it's considered a special resource ("_next"). in gh-pages.

In this situation, how should I change the "touch" command for normal operation?

In this situation, how should I change the "touch" command for normal operation?

Comment: This question belongs on another SE site and it has already an answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command you are looking for is the following:

```
New-Item -Name out/.nojekyll -ItemType File
```